# Strategy to edit my "Plato 5040" question in order to get it reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[Just how much did Plato really know about the number 5040?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/13844/3869) was closed for "opinion-based" and I can see that "Just how much did Plato really know..." is impossible to answer. My bad.

I'd like to ask if he recognized (in writing) any mathematical qualities about the number 5040 itself *beyond* that it can be even divided by 1 through 10 and 12. Specifically I'm curious what else he *wrote* about its factors.

In order to edit the question and try to get it reopened, I'm asking for some advice how best to modify the wording.

Should I just ask "What did Plato write about the number 5040 itself?" and adjust the rest of the wording to match that?

Is there a different way to phrase the question that might be more likely to get it reopened?

Answer (score 1):

I would focus on what Plato *wrote* about the number $5040$, rather than what he *knew* about it. Furthermore (and this is perhaps more important), I would remove any question about Plato recognizing $5040$ as a highly composite number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm particularly interested in scrutinizing the statement in the block quote "Jean-Pierre Kahane has suggested that Plato's use of the number 5040 marks the first appearance of the concept of a highly composite number..."  and the first comment suggests a definitive answer to that is possible. I'm curious why you would recommend that I remove it?

Comment: Because that will probably be opinion-based, unless Plato wrote something about it (which I doubt).

Comment: I was hoping that would be covered by implementing the "what Plato wrote about" change. Hmm... maybe I have two separate questions here. a) "What did Plato write about the number 5040 itself?" and separately b) "Did Plato's use of the number 5040 mark the first appearance of the concept of a highly composite number as Kahane suggests?" It seems it's best to convert my question to a) and *think about* asking b) separately, later. This is very helpful, *thanks!*